Use SMD or raw difference in proportions when comparing balance of binary covariates used in propensity matching?
I am a junior in the medical field, and have been tasked with performing a propensity matched analysis of some data, using R.
I am looking at comparing the balance of my covariates (both before and after matching), and looking through the documentation for the cobalt package it says that continuous covariates will have the SMD shown, where as for binary variables the raw difference in proportion is automatically calculated.
I am aware I can change which I ask it to calculate, however I am after some guidance as to which  I should use?
Looking through propensity-matched papers published in some of the higher-impact medical journals, as well as papers that report on how to report propensity scores and matching in the medical literature (eg. DOI: 10.1002/sim.3697; doi:10.1136/bmjopen-2020-036961; doi.org/10.1016/j.jtcvs.2007.07.021; and doi: 10.21037/atm.2018.12.10), they all seem to imply that the SMD is calculated and not the raw difference (or any mention of binary variables at all).
Looking through what has been documented in medical literature/medical statistics literature, I am unable to find any clear guidance on if I should use SMD or raw differnce.
As such, I have used SMD in my calculations so far

Let's think about why we compute standardized mean differences at all. Consider the following balance table



Variable
Treated Mean
Control Mean
Mean Diff
SMD




Age (yrs)
40
35
5
.3


Income ($)
40,000
27,000
13,000
.4


Risk Score
8
6
2
.7


Female
.6
.5
.1
.2


Vaccinated
.95
.85
.1
.46



The first three variables are continuous, and the last two are binary.
Let's focus on the Mean Diff column. For Age, we have a mean difference of 5, for Income we have a mean difference of 13,000, and for Risk Score, we have a mean difference of 2. From those numbers alone, we have no idea whether our samples are well-balanced. That's because these numbers are all on different scales. For Risk Score, we don't even know what the scale is. There is no simple way to assess whether any individual variable is balanced or to compare balance across these three variables. If you have subject matter expertise, you might be able to understand that a 5 year age difference represents a slight imbalance. For risk score, though, a difference of 2 might not seem like much, but without knowing to what degree risk scores vary within groups or what the known range is for the population you're studying, it is essentially meaningless.
Standardizing the mean differences solves these problems: it puts the mean differences on a common scale so the imbalance across variables can be understood intuitively without expert knowledge of the scale of the variables and allows imbalances to be compared across variables on different scales. This makes it easy to take a glance at a balance table and see which variables need attention in the matching or whether balance has been achieved overall in the sample.
Do those benefits occur with binary variables? Let's take a look at the two binary variables Female and Vaccinated. For both variables, the mean difference is .1, i.e., a 10 percentage point difference between the two groups on each variable. This number makes sense and can be intuitively understood; no subject matter expertise is required to take in this number. For both variables, .1 means the same thing. There is no need to transform these scales into something more interpretable because a difference in proportion is already comprehensible and can be compared across variables of the same type.
Take a look at the SMDs for those variables, though. They are vastly different (and these are real numbers computed using the treated group standard deviation in the standardization factor). Even though the mean differences are the same, the standardized mean differences tell a completely different story, with Vaccinated appearing far more imbalanced than Female. That's because for a binary variable, the standard deviation (which is used in the standardization factor) depends on the mean of the variable. But the mean of the variable has nothing to do with the balance of that variable. By computing the SMD of a binary variable, we unnecessarily change the scale into one completely uninterpretable (what is the standard deviation of a binary variable?), one that incorrectly suggests some variables are more imbalanced than others, and one that incorporates information completely irrelevant to imbalance into the imbalance statistic. You can see how, if I were to create a package that promoted best practices in balance assessment, I might not want to make computing SMDs the default for binary variables.
That's not to say there are no good arguments for using the SMD for binary variables. The standardization factor always makes the SMD larger than the raw mean differences for binary variables, so if you aim for acceptable balance using the SMD, you are aiming for even better balance based on the raw mean difference. Also, we often have both binary and continuous variables in the same balance table; it is a bit awkward to have both raw mean differences and SMDs in the same location in a table. While it's not immediately clear that standardizing the mean differences for binary variables is necessary to facilitate comparison with continuous variables, at least the statistic is computed the same and has the same name. In fact, if you try to make a Love plot using cobalt::love.plot(), you will get a warning saying that different statistics are being presented in a plot at the same time.
What should you do? One option is to follow the norms in your field. You are writing to inform people in your field about your study. You should present data in a way that will be comprehensible to them. The marginal benefit of being "technically correct" is rarely worth the confusion it can cause people who are expecting information presented in a way that is more intuitive to them. Alternatively, you can present both the SMD and the KS statistic. For continuous variables, the KS statistic is a scale-free measure of the overall balance of the covariate beyond just the difference in means. For binary variables, the KS statistic is just the raw difference in means. By presenting the SMD and the KS statistic for all variables, you include important information while retaining interpretability where it is needed.
In cobalt, you can request the KS statistic by adding stats = c("m", "ks") in the call to bal.tab() (don't forget to set binary = "std" to get SMDs for binary variables!). In MatchIt, the statistic ecdf max is the same as the KS statistic, and SMDs are computed for all variables by default.
